# changing the tab in the shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to mimic this specific shiny app. https://columbia.shinyapps.io/yingli/
I haven't found similar apps with access to the code.
I have Leonardo DiCaprio gif in the background, but I would like to know how to add tabs the same way as the app below, and if you click on the right directional key, it will go to other tabs, within the tab.

```
if (interactive()) {
  
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyWidgets)
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$h2("Add a shiny app background image"),
    setBackgroundImage(
      src = "https://blog.hubspot.com/hubfs/Smiling%20Leo%20Perfect%20GIF.gif"
    ),
    titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
      
      sidebarPanel(
        
        sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                    label = "Number of bins:",
                    min = 1,
                    max = 50,
                    value = 30)

        
      ),
      mainPanel(

        plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")

      )
    )
    
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    # 2. Its output type is a plot
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      
      x    <- faithful$waiting
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
      
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
           xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
           main = "Histogram of waiting times")
      
    })
    
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
  
}
```

Comment: Seems to be based on the following package: https://github.com/RinteRface/fullPage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, here's a example using the awesome `fullPage` library mentioned in the comments:

```
# Dependencies install
# install.packages("remotes")
# remotes::install_github("RinteRface/fullPage")

library(shiny)
library(fullPage)

options <- list(
  sectionsColor = c('#f2f2e2', '#f2f2f2', '#f2f2f2'),
  parallax = TRUE
)

ui <- fullPage(
  menu = c("Full Page" = "tab1","Sections" = "tab2","Image" = "tab3"),
  opts = options,
  fullSection(
    center = TRUE,
    menu = "tab1",
    tags$h1("fullPage.js meets Shiny")
  ),
  fullSection(
    menu = "tab2",
    fullRow(
      fullColumn(
        sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                    label = "Number of bins:",
                    min = 1,
                    max = 50,
                    value = 30)
      ),
      fullColumn(
        plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
      )
    )
  ),
  fullSectionImage(
    menu = "tab3",
    img = "https://blog.hubspot.com/hubfs/Smiling%20Leo%20Perfect%20GIF.gif"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    
    x    <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
         xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
         main = "Histogram of waiting times")
    
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Although the `fullpage.js` library that it is used allow some configuration to use `left/right` keys to navigate, the shiny wrapper library above doesn't seem to expose that setting - I could only disable/enable the keyboard, but not choose direction.